# Объясните задержку при вызове Task

Tags: c#, многопоточность

При выполнении следующего кода наблюдаю картину, что несколько (3-4) выводов в консоль отрабатывают быстро, а затем следующие выводятся очень медленно.
Ожидаю, что потоки будут запускаться быстро, выводить данные в консоль, ждать 60 с и завершаться. Почему не так?
Использование TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning ситуацию несколько улучшает, но хочется понять в какие ограничения я упираюсь.

```
            for (int step = 0; step < 10000000; step++)
        {
            int index = step;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("index=" + index);
                Console.WriteLine("thread=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(60000);                    
            });
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно, вы сделали несколько потоков и усыпили их. Они спят, но управление не отдают. Пока какой-то поток не закончится, новые не стартуют - у среды исполнения просто нет для этого свободных потоков. Если хотите, чтобы спящий поток не блокировал исполнение других потоков, используйте асинхронную версию задержки - `await Task.Delay(60000);`, она будет отдавать управление.

Пример можно посмотреть [в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_Int32_), однако вам нужно не ждать как там исполнения каждой задачи через `t.Wait()`, а, например, собрать все созданные таким образом задачи в один массив и потом сделать Task.WaitAll(), чтобы подождать окончания сразу всех созданных задач одновременно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

## Когда вы используете `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, вы стартуете по сути новый поток.

Запуск потока - дорогая операция. Сам поток - затратный ресурс.

Более того, предположим, что процессор выделил на ваш процесс 10 секунд, за 10 секунд он должен обойти ваши потоки и каждому потоку выделить какое то время.

Предположим, что ваш процессор однопоточный, а переключение его между потоками занимает 1 секунду (переключение между потоками - это дорогая операция).

Имея 2 потока на процесс, за 10 секунд процессор успеет отработать 5 секунд на первом потоке, потом секунда на переклчение и потом еще 4 секунды на второй поток.

Когда у вас 4 потока, то процессор 3 секунды потратит на переключения, 3 потока получат по 2 скуеды работы, один отработает 1 секунду.

Когда у вас 10 потоков, то процессор потратит все время на переключение между потоками и каждый поток получит минимум времени или совсем не получит.

Ну а теперь представьте, какая работа будет выполнена, если у вас условно 10 процессоров и 10000000 потоков.

Так как вы создаете потоки один за другим и потоки стартуют не сразу, у вас поначалу все более-менее работает. Как только потоков становится огромное количество, то потоки начинют тупить, так как на каждый поток процессор тратит все меньше и меньше времени.

## Когда вы не используете `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, вы по сути не знаете, будет ли для вас создан новый поток или задача будет поставлена в пул потоков.

Если задача будет поставлена в пул потоков, который имеет огарничение на количество потоков, то вы можете оказаться в ситуации, что вы своим `thread.sleep` заблокировали все потоки в пуле, и вам придется ждать, пока какой-то из потоков не освободится, чтобы выполнить очередную задачу. Потому в это случае вы можете увидеть, что первые несколько сообщений прошли быстро, а после надо ждать ваш таймаут, чтобы обработать очередное сообщение.

---

А вообще, вы поизучайте вопрос. Я уверен, что вы найдете рекомендацию, что `Task.Factory.StartNew` лучше использовать только когда вы знаете, что делаете. Когда не знаете - то начните с `Task.Run`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Есть возможность узнать, сколько реально времени тратится на переключение между потоками? И заодно состояние и текущие ограничения пула потоков в приложении.

Comment: По поводу пула потоков - смотрите документацию по ThreadPool, я на память не помню, что там есть. По поводу замеров - переключение между потоками называется `переключение контекста`. Контекст - это состояние потока, которое включает локальное хранилище потока  или, например, стек потока. Я не думаю, что есть смысл в замере времени переключения, так как на разных процессорах и разной глубиной вложенности стека оно может быть разным. Но вот, например, кто то пытался замерить https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-cost-of-context-switches/